# Is there a method to modify bits in IP packets with OpenFlow?

Tags: switch, network, ipv6, sdn, openflow

We've already known that `ovs-ofctl` provides many actions to modify packets like `set_field`, `load`, `move`...

but I can't find a suitable action or action combination to modify a bit in the IP packet destinations field.

In other words, when we received packets the destination ipv6 field is `2020::1` or `2020::2`, we make the destinations field become `2010::1` or `2010::2` by OpenFlow rules.

I try to assemble `set_field`, `load`, `move` and others to do this, but it seems that it doesn't work.

Can we achieve this simply by `ovs-ofctl` or not?

Comment: That is called NAT (Network Address Translation), and it is often used for IPv4. IPv6 does not have NAT standards the way IPv4 does. There is an _Experimental_ RFC for IPv6 NAT, but it only allows 1:1 NAT, not NAPT the way that is normally used with IPv4. In fact, it expressly forbids NAPT. Also, besides modifying the IPv6 address, you would then need to recalculate the transport protocol checksum for things like TCP and UDP. IPv6 doesn't have a header checksum like IPv4, so it requires the upper-layer protocols to do that.

Comment: I can't support,  highlight and upvote Ron's comment enough. If the network design requires IPv6 NAT, it might be a bad design. It is strongly preferrable to find another solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I used `NXM_NX_IPV6_DST` field and `load` action to resolve this problem on openvswitch bridge by adding a flow 
as follows

```
ovs-ofctl -O openflow13 add-flow br0 "priority=60000,ipv6,ipv6_dst=2020::/16,actions=load:0x2010->NXM_NX_IPV6_DST[112..127]"
```